# cart total in Django shows blank space

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, cart

I'm trying to get cart total sum of products in the html template, while the the total sum of particular products works fine, the cart total price/quantity shows blank spaces.

Models:

```
from django.db import models

import Accounts.models as accounts_models
import Products.models as products_models


class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(accounts_models.Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderproducts = self.orderproduct_set.all()
        total = sum([product.get_total for product in orderproducts])
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_products(self):
        orderproducts = self.orderproduct_set.all()
        total = sum([product.quantity for product in orderproducts])
        return total


class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(products_models.Products, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total
```

views:

```
def cart(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderproduct_set.all()
    else:
        items = []
    context = {'items': items}
    return render(request, 'cart.html', context)
```

html template:

```
                {% for item in items %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ item.product.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
                        <td>${{ item.product.price }}</td>
                        <td>${{ item.get_total }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
                    <td>${{ order.get_cart_total }}</td>
                </tr>
```

How can I start showing the total numbers in the html template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't pass order in your cart view, here is updated view:

```
def cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderproduct_set.all()
    else:
        items = []
        order = None  # Add this line to handle the case when there is no order
    context = {'items': items, 'order': order}  # Add the order object to the context dictionary
    return render(request, 'cart.html', context)
```